# Python: TypeError: 'str' object is not callable Rating System

Tags: python, typeerror

When I run this code:

```
def printPredictions(matches):
    pPredictionTable = PrettyTable()
    pPredictionTable.field_names = ["Player 1", "Player 2", "Difference", "Winner"]
    for match in matches:
        p1 = match['teamA']
        p2 = match['teamB']
        if match['aBeatb'] == True:
            pPredictionTable.add_row([match['teamA'], match['teamB'], match['difference'], p1])             
        else:
            pPredictionTable.add_row([match['teamA'], match['teamB'], match['difference'], p2])

    print(pPredictionTable)    

printPredictions(pmatches)
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ericr_000\Desktop\PyDev\NPA-2-Rating-System\Rankings.py", line 645, in <module>
    printPredictions()
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I have pmatches as a separate dictionary, and I don't have the coding skills to fix this issue.  (Line 145 is printPredictions(pmatches)

Comment: Your error is in `printPredictions`, not in `makePredictions`. Please post the necessary code...

Comment: Can you also clearly identify which is line 645

Comment: Somewhere in your code you have `(`brackets `)` after a string.  You haven't posted the right function to tell, but it will look something like this: `iAmAStringVar('thingy')`

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting `'str' object is not callable` when you try to call `printPredictions`, that means that by the time your program reaches line 645, the name `printPredictions` was reassigned to a string. Somewhere in your code you have something like

```
printPredictions = someStringValueGoesHere
```

You should choose a different name for that variable, or delete the line entirely.

```
foobar = someStringValueGoesHere
```